# Pop Up Damage indicator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, apex, frame-rate

Hello i just started coding with Unity, my main source for information are youtube videos i watched Brackeys 3rd Person and 1st Person tutorials. I already coded a couple of test games, yesterday night i started to code my new test game which will be a little hero shooter i'd like to send my friends after i finished, i implemented a character controller (Jumping, Running, Sprinting, Shooting). Well i talked enough about my journey so far, my problem or lets say my question is how do i let the damage Pop up like in Apex Legends or other similar games. Would be great if you could give me some code examples.
Btw i am 15 years old so i aint so experienced.

Comment: Welcome to so. Your question is unpopular because this covered many places on the Internet and as a group we don’t just write code for people. Even if it isn’t hard. Have a google. There is a lot on places about this to achieve a look you are after. 

Mostly so is for code issues and so showing what you have and why it’s not working and showing there is effort goes a long way

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to give you any details about what exactly to do, but you should take a look at Unity Particle Systems.

Another option I am currently using is to instantiate Text Objects that fly into a random direction and fade away over time. You can for example instantiate such a Text Object every time the Enemy is hit by a bullet. The Text has to be set equal to the damage you dealt by the specific bullet.
This could be useful for having Pop-Up Damage Indicators.